# Attribute aria-polite not allowed on element a at this point

Tags: html, w3c-validation, wai-aria

I have this html code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" class="twitter-timeline" data-widget-id="X" data-theme="dark" data-chrome="transparent" data-tweet-limit="1" aria-polite="polite">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
```

But when I try to validate this code with http://validator.w3.org/ it shows me this error:

```
"Attribute aria-polite not allowed on element a at this point"
```

Anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `aria-polite` attribute.

Maybe you mean the [`aria-live` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live) with the value `polite`?

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot!!

I changed aria-polite by aria-live.